# Cisco 9500 switch stack

Tags: cisco, stacking

I have a cisco 9500 switch that is live/up in productions but I need assistance or more information on how to add a few more switches to create a switch stack and would like to be pointed in the right direction.

Thank you all for the assistance.

Comment: The Catalyst 9500s are not stackable switches. The Catalyst 9200 and 9300 are stackable, and the Catalyst 9400 is a chassis.

Comment: I'm sorry I did some more research and found that the only way this will work is by doing a StackWise Virtual Configuration

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

As R3ne mentioned, the Cisco Catalyst 9000 series supports StackWise Virtual features that replace the older generation StackWise capability from previous generation Catalyst fixed config switches.

More information on the concept and implementation are available here:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-9000/nb-06-cat-9k-stack-wp-cte-en.html

The end result should be very similar in most ways to traditional stacking but with improved redundancy and data plane traffic management as well as improved redundancy and non-stop forwarding. The newer switches also support faster links for the Virtual StackWise links (40 Gigabit or more vs. 16 Gigabit [32 Gigabit with dual cables] on older StackWise dedicated cables or 10 Gigabit VSS links).